# Avoiding forward declaration and circular reference in C++

Tags: object-oriented, c++, object-oriented-design

Consider a card game (something like Magic or Legends of Runeterra) program, with `BaseCard`, `Deck` and `GameState` classes/structs. The way I've conceptualized the relationship between these classes would be something like this:

BaseCard.hpp

```
struct GameState;

class BaseCard
{
public:
    virtual void DoEffect(GameState &gameState) = 0;
};
```

Deck.hpp

```
struct Deck
{
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseCard>> drawPile;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseCard>> discardPile;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseCard>> hand;
};
```

GameState.hpp

```
struct GameState
{
    std::unique_ptr<Deck> deck;
};
```

The idea is that cards might have a variety of different effects that can change the `GameState`, like draw cards, alter properties of cards currently in hand, recover player health and so on, which would be implemented in `DoEffect`. I want the possibilities of what a card can do to be very flexible and I can't think of a way to that which doesn't involve passing the `GameState` to the card, but at the same time the cards are also inherently part of the game state.

Naturally I can get the code to compile by using a forward declaration in `BaseCard.hpp` then including `GameState.hpp` in the cpp files with the concrete implementations of the classes that inherit `BaseCard`, but this feels kinda "hacky" to me...

So my question here is whether this type of pattern is actually ok/normal in C++, and if not, what are possible alternatives.

Comment: "whether this type of pattern is actually ok/normal in C++" Yes.

Comment: As an aside: you probably don't need `std::unique_ptr<Deck>` unless you plan subclasses of `Deck`

Comment: This kind of forward declaration has practically no contents. All you can do is declare that a name is a struct or a class. You can’t even forward declare that a class is a subclass of a known class. I think that kind of use is perfectly fine.